# Calling a step within a step that has a parameter set

Tags: python-behave

I know that I can use the

```
context.execute_steps('given I have logged in')
```

syntax to run a step within  step

and if the step has a variable parameter within it I can hard code this in the step eg

```
@when('the user selects {value}')
```

becomes

```
context.execute_steps('when the user selects blue')
```

However is there a way of keeping the variable and passing that in from the step being run eg

```
@when(the user does a thing and then selects {value})
def step_impl(context, value)
    context.execute_steps('given the user does a thing')
    context.execute_steps('when the user selects {value}')
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can simply use python string formatting.

```
@when(the user does a thing and then selects {value})
def step_impl(context, value)
    context.execute_steps('given the user does a thing')
    context.execute_steps('when the user selects {0}'.format(value))
```

or using old style python string formatting

```
@when(the user does a thing and then selects {value})
def step_impl(context, value)
    context.execute_steps('given the user does a thing')
    context.execute_steps('when the user selects %s'%value)
```

Answer (score 0):

or as per documentation. Below example with f'strings.

```
@when(the user does a thing and then selects {value}) 
def step_impl(context, value):
    context.execute_steps(
        f'''
        given the user does a thing
        when the user selects "{value}"
        '''
    )
```